# Income tax paid in India as well as in U.S. Anyways to claim double taxation?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, income-tax-refund, dtaa

I had been on Short Time Assignment for 92 days (1-Jan-2014 to 1-Apr-2014) in U.S. During this period income tax on my salary (for duration of my stay in U.S) has been deducted in India. I also received some incentives. On the incentives also income tax has been deducted in India.

This year I have to undergo U.S Taxation process as my stay in US was more than 89 days. For the U.S taxation salary paid in India, incentives and applicable daily bonus has been considered for tax calculation.

So in short I have paid tax for salary (for duration of my stay in U.S) and incentives in India as well as in US.

Is there any way to adjust/reclaim tax paid in U.S. in Indian income tax.
There is double taxation avoidance treaty but I am not able to understand much.
Can anyone help me in this matter?

Comment: Doesn't your company provide accountant to deal with relocation-related tax issues? You'll need to file a tax return in India and claim credit for the US taxes paid for that period, check with a local tax accountant on the details.

Answer (score 1):

India and US have a DTAA and you can claim relief to the extent of taxes paid. Please consult a CA would will help you with the specifics of your case.

Related question

[233 days India/132 days US - entire US salary taxable in India?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39986/233-days-india-132-days-us-entire-us-salary-taxable-in-india)